# Azure Automation - Azure API Management backup to blob storage

Tags: powershell, azure-api-management, azure-automation

I have set up an automation account and a graphical workflow with PowerShell to backup to blob storage.

I Realised that Azure automation was missing the required APIM commandlets so I imported them. I can now see these within my Automation assets:

[image]

Here is my graphical PowerShell workflow:
[image]

However, **Backup-AzureRmApiManagement** is not available:
[image]

Can anyone tell me why?

thanks
Russ

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I didn't think there was a valid reason for this. I deleted my imported modules (even though azure said they were available (imported correctly)) and re-imported.

Now the Backup-AzureRmApiManagement is available:
[image]

Just be careful when importing PowerShell module into Azure. It may look like they imported correctly but some things might be missing or broken.